# Calculate the Laplace transform

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Help me calculate the Laplace transform of a geometric series.
$$
 f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nu(t-n)
$$

show that 
$$
\mathcal{L} \{f(t)\} = \frac{1}{s(1+\mathcal{e}^{-s})}
$$

Edit:
 so far I know that

$$
\mathcal{L} \{f(t)\} = \frac{1}{s}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-ns}
$$

Comment: I assume $u(t)$ is the Heavise Step function?

Comment: Hint: What is the Laplace transform of the shift $u_x(\cdot)\mapsto u(\cdot-x)$? (Use a change of variable).

Comment: I added some extra information as to where I get stuck

Comment: Write the series as ${1\over s} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \bigl(-e^{-s}\bigr)^n$ and apply the formula giving the sum of a convergent Geometric series. (I think the proposed answer is off...)

Comment: Got it. I guess that is what I had trouble seeing

Comment: So, $\cal L\{f(t)\}$  should be ${1\over s(1+e^{-s})}$, correct?.

Comment: For $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-e^{-s})^n$, the ratio is $r=-e^{-s}$, so the sum is ${1\over 1-r}={1\over 1-(-e^{-s})}={1\over 1+e^{-s}}$; or, am I off?

Comment: @DavidMitra That is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach.

Note that for $t>0$, we have $f(t)+f(t-1) = 1$. The Laplace transform of a time-shifted function (in this case $f(t-1) = f(t-1) u(t-1)$) is $s \mapsto e^{-s} \hat{f}$, where $\hat{f}$ is the Laplace transform of $f$. Furthermore, the Laplace transform of $1$ is just $s \mapsto \frac{1}{s}$. Hence we have
$$\hat{f}(s)+ e^{-s} \hat{f}(s) = \frac{1}{s},$$
from which it follows that

$$\hat{f}(s) = \frac{1}{s(1+e^{-s})}.$$
(Your formula above is incorrect.)

Comment: That is certainly a clever solution!

Answer (score 3):

Try to think what your sum looks like. You will see it is a periodic function, with period $2$, that we can define as.

$$f(t) = 1 ; 0<t<1$$

$$f(t) = 0 ; 1<t<2$$

In general if a function has period $P$, it's LP is given by

$$\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} =\frac{1}{1-e^{-sP}}\int_0^P e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

under appropriate conditions (i.e. the LP should exist)

It this case $f(t)$ is periodically constant, so the LP exists, and

$$\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} =\frac{1}{1-e^{-2s}}\int_0^2 e^{-st}f(t)dt$$

$$\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} =\frac{1}{1-e^{-2s}}\int_0^1e^{-st}dt$$

$$\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} =\frac{1}{1-e^{-2s}}\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}$$

$$\mathcal L \{ f(t) \} =\frac{1}{1+e^{-s}}\frac{1}{s}$$

Answer (score 0):

A two-step solution:

Fact 1. $L\big[H_n(t)]=\frac{e^{-pn}}{p};$

Fact 2. $\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{e^{-pn}}{p}=\frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{1+e^{-p}},\;\;
Rep>0.$

Here, $H_n(t)=u(t-n).$