# Laplace Transform of a Geometric Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to graph the following function

$f(t) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n u(t-n)$

($u$ refers to the unit step function)

and find the laplace transform of this function.

The problem is similar to another one posted here
[Calculate the Laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142683/calculate-the-laplace-transform)
except for mine i need to graph a function and it is slightly different.

Comment: If $t>0$, $u(t-0) = 1$, so the Laplace transforms will be the same. Why don't you just graph the functions $t \mapsto 1-u(t-1)$, and $t \mapsto 1-u(t-1)+u(t-2)$ and guess what the general pattern is. The graph is fairly simple.

Comment: me and a classmate sketched the graph,

Comment: me and a classmate sketched a graph that looked like 
f(1) = 1 + (-1) = 0
f(2) = 1 + (-1) +1 = 1 
f(3) = 1 + (-1) +1 + (-1) = 0
f(4) = 1 + (-1) +1 + (-1) +1 = 1 

not to sure if that's how you sketch piecewise functions

Comment: It should look like a square wave...

Comment: so from 0 to 1  f(t) = 0 
and from 1 to 2 f(t) = 1 
(from here it repeated itself) 

and we took the laplace 
1/(1-e^(-sT) * integral from 0 to 2 of e^-(st)f(t)dt 
which is than split up into two integrals, 

the first from 0 to 1 (but since f(t) is 0 on this range it becomes 0) 

the second from 1 to 2 
1/(1-e^(-2s) integral from 1 to 2 e^-(st)dt 

and i'm not sure if we simplified it right, 
but the answer came out to 
1/(s(e^s+1)

Comment: Yeah i looked up pictures of the square wave on google,

Comment: my graph didn't look like it :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's my picture, you should get the pattern from this...

[image: Approaching a square wave...]

Comment: Maybe your can write some values in the axis!

Comment: Well, the values on the y-axis are just $0$ and $1$, the values on the x-axis are just $0,1,2,...$.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab Program

```
  t=0:0.01:10;
  G=zeros(1,length(t));
  for n=1:10
      G1=(-1)^n*heaviside(t-n);
      G=G+G1;
  end
  F=1+G;
  plot(t,F)
  axis([0 10 -2 2])
```

[image]